# how to Eliminate render-blocking resources for font

Tags: performance, next.js, fonts

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import Script from "next/script";

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head>

        <link
          rel="preconnect"
          href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
        <link
          rel="preconnect"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alfa+Slab+One&family=Gentium+Book+Basic:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        
          />
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

I am working on next js Project i tried preconnect and preload font but still getting Eliminate render-blocking resources Potential savings of 1,400 ms

Comment: You're loading quite a few fonts (3 different families) in 2 link elements. You may try to combine the query in one like so `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alfa+Slab+One&family=Gentium+Book+Basic:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700` I highly recommend to reduce the number of fonts if feasible